# Minimal example of Metafont file and how using it

Tags: fonts, fontspec, metafont

I need create simple utf-8 characters font with 4 glyphs.
characters = a,ą,ā,ȧ
I would like to use it in normal latex roman font (mixing standard rm font and my).

Where is working minimal example of parameters font in metafont. *.mf file. How seting kerning between glyph and how defining acute over the glyph and create new glyph?

I foud some example but only for 'a' file **test.tex**

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}

\newfont{\letterbeta}{beta}
\newcommand{\literaa}{{\letterbeta a}}
\begin{document}
Czy nasz glif działa czy nie?{\Large Sprawdzimy \literaa\ tutaj} i tutaj \literaa.
%\small\tiny\big etc. in latex
\literaa\literaa
\end{document}
```

and file **beta.mf**

```
font_identifier := "fontusik";
mode_setup;

%cmchar "Litera a";
% Litera a lub cyfrowo 97
beginchar("a",11pt#,11pt#,0);
% Zmienne i koordynaty
 y1=y2=y3=0; y4=y5=y6=h; x1=x4=0; x2=x5=w; x3=x6=2*w;
%not working?
%showmsg("h=", h/1mm );
% Definiujemy pióro
 pickup pencircle xscaled 0.2w yscaled 0.4w rotated 45;
% Rysujemy linię
 draw z1..z3..z6{z2-z6}..z5..{z4-z2}z4..cycle;
% showit;
penlabels(z1,z3,z4);
endchar;

bye.
```

Makefile:

```
test.dvi : test.tex
        mf '\mode=ljfour; mode_setup; input beta.mf'
        gftopk beta.600gf beta.600pk
        pdflatex test.tex
```

How seting right space between chars, and chars uper 256

Comment: i don't mean to be discouraging, but if you create a font with metafont, you well be limiting yourself to bitmaps.  you might want to take a look at `metatype1`, with which scaleable postscript-compatible fonts can be produced through input code similar to that used with metafont.

Comment: latex today is complicated , and unicode char map and ligatures is complicated too ;-) I waiting for white knights , who create example and put them on github.

Comment: metafont and pdflatex can not handle unicode fonts so it isn't clear what you mean by a "utf-8 characters font"  . Most of the characters you show are above U+00FF so would need to be added (somewhere) in a custom 8-bit encoding. But it isn't clear why you need a font `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` should already allow input of ą etc, and constructing a suitable representation for pdftex?

Comment: (1) If you simply want to use the characters a,ą,ā,ȧ, they are already available without you creating a new font. (2) If you *do* want to create a new font (that is: you want to change the shape of `a`, and the shape you desire is not available in *any* font that exists in the world), then you can use a modern font-creation tool like Fontforge or (if you like Metafont syntax) `metatype1`. (3) If you *really* want to use Metafont (note that it produces bitmap fonts), then please acknowledge the above points, and confirm that this is really what you want, and say why, and what you've tried. :-)

Comment: Its very clear ;-) I need new font, and new representation glyph of chars "a,ą,ā,ȧ". In latex I can use utf8 characters. How I can do this and using it in latex?

Comment: Mastering Metafont to the point pf being able to draw an ”a“ requires weeks/months of study. Integrating the new letterforms in an existing font requires mastery and hours of work.

Comment: @egreg forget form, show me how do this. I need only 'size' will be similar. How creating char above 256, how using it, how create ligatures, and create styles (if needed)

Comment: @NeumiaszEr you can not have any characters above 256 in metafont or pdftex as I said in  the comment above. Both systems are restricted to 8bit fonts with 256 characters.

Comment: Ha ha, Ci co nie umieją odpowiedzieć chcą udupić pytanie.

Comment: This is good questions, why on hold?

Comment: Although… you don't *need* characters above 256. You can put your four characters at positions 0, 1, 2, 3 in the font (say) and ask for those characters when you want them typeset. For creating new glyphs… read *The Metafontbook*

Comment: @ShreevatsaR ok, i show how create one glyph, how using it in latex similar other utf8 char? In normal latex i can use ąćź how tell tex to use my glyph as normal utf8 chars? This is a question. Question is how using what i create.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0227}{\.a}
\begin{document}
a, ą, ā, ȧ 
\par
a, \k{a}, \={a}, \.{a}
\end{document}
`

Comment: @Johannes_B \DeclareUnicodeCharacter is from wich font? Please, Can You answer and put all together? simple copy above code 'beta'. It will be working with \tiny\large\small switches etc? What is lmodern package? Why this not working with lualatex ?

Comment: Package `lmodern` provides accented letters (output/font) for nearly all latin scripts, it is based on Computer Modern. Package `inputenc` takes care of the accented letters (input) and translates your unicode input to the bottom line, which pdflatex understands. LuaTeX can handle any unicode input, if package `fontspec`  is loaded (and the font has the glyph).

Comment: @Johannes_B Many thanks
I create small example: ![example produce](http://bankfotek.pl/image/2095086). 
Why _ is not above my modyfy ȧ ? %!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \newfont{\letterbeta}{beta}
    \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0227}{{\letterbeta a}}
    \begin{document} a, ą, ā, ȧ
    \par a, \k{a}, \={ȧ}, \.{a}
\par {\tiny a, ą, ā, ȧ}
\end{document}  Tell me why You not would like to answer this questions?

Comment: I don't know. Your question still is completely unclear to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65337/discussion-between-neumiasz-er-and-johannes-b).

Comment: \par a, \k{a}, \={ȧ}, \.{a}
\par {\tiny a, ą, ā, ȧ} How create correct file latex+metafont? to produce correct output.